# Listing vertices per face in python blender (bpy)

Tags: python, blender, bpy

In Blender using Python I am trying to list the vertices of each face in a clockwise manner.
I can list all faces, I can list all vertices, how do I fix the below script to loop through all faces and while doing so print the vertices (clockwise order)?

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)


for f in bm.faces:
    if f.select:
        print(f.index)
        for v in bm.verts:
            print(v.co)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each face lists its verts in [`BMFace.verts`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace.verts). The verts list appears to always be sorted counter-clockwise when looking at the front of the face, so `reversed(f.verts)` should give what you want.

```
for f in bm.faces:
    if f.select:
        print(f.index)
        for v in reversed(f.verts):
            print(v.index, v.co)
```